# Need some eyes on my dataset: can we argue here that there is a random spread around a constant?

Tags: data-visualization, dataset, generalized-additive-model

I have this huge data set where I am looking to find trends. However, this one quantity (Figure) seems to randomly spread around an almost constant line (with the exception between 1600-2300). I did fit a GAM smoothing spline to find some slight variation, but I think since this fluctuation is way smaller than the spread around the line it seems to me that it is negligible and just due to randomness.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = xVal, y = yVal)) +
geom_smooth(method="gam", formula = y~s(x,bs="cr"), color='red')
```

[image]

Can someone help me to argue my hypothesis that the quantity randomly spreads around an almost constant line? Some idea how I can handle the area 1600-2300?

My approach so far: I used the smoothing spline to account slightly for the fluctuation. Next I calculated the standard deviation of the residuals (~ 21.3) to argue that the spread is very big, bigger than the fluctuation itself (~ 10-15). But I am not quite confident if this is a good approach nor how to discuss the outbreak between 1600-2300 (maybe with some confident band which is stretched strongly down at this area).

Some tips to my approach or also a different approach, both is very much appreciated!

Comment: You really haven't fitted a GAM. Use *mgcv* directly to fit the model and be sure to check the sufficiency of the basis dimension (how many basis functions used), because I wouldn't trust any inference or statistic generated from the model you show fitted to those data as the model clearly isn't suited to these data.

Comment: As of my unterstanding of the help function of ggplot2, the function does fit the gam by use of the mgcv library, using the formula above.
However, I am interested in your comment that "the model clearly isn't suited to these data". Do you have a better model suggestion that I might should tryout for this data? Do you need more information?

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following: Measure how far your spline is from the straight horizontal line. Then generate a bunch of sets of random data. Fit a spline to each set and see how many have bigger differences between a straight line and the spline than yours does.

The exact nature of the random data could be a few different things - one choice is to use data that has mean at the mean of your line and the same sd, with a normally distributed error.

Comment: Dear Mr Flom, thank you very much for you insight.

Comment: Can I ask you for some more explainations:
"Measure how far"/"bigger differences": do you think of mean squared error?
"same sd" as spline: from the plot it seems to me that we do not have constant variance. Is there a way to do this with a non constant variance approach? (Maybe use bootstrap; generating new sets from the given data) Or is it okay to just take the average standart deviation?

Comment: You could look at area between the curves. And you could generate the data for whatever particulars of your data you think are important.